# VB.Net Async using Await properly

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

I'm using VB.Net, MVC 5, Visual Studio 2013.  I have a question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106363/mvc-net-view-model) on code review, in which it was suggested I make some of my view model functions asynchronous.  I am trying to implement this suggestion.

I have a method in my view model which is called by an action (this portion seems to be working well):

```
Async Function getItemHistory(itemID As Integer, itemTypeID As Integer) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ItemHistoryPresentationModel)
    Dim returnModel = New ItemHistoryPresentationModel

    Dim getOperatorsTask As Task(Of List(Of String)) = getOperatorsAsync(itemID)
    Dim getItemNameTask As Task(Of String) = getItemNameAsync(itemTypeID)

    Await Task.WhenAll(getOperatorsTask, getItemNameTask)

    returnModel.ItemTypeString = getItemNameTask.Result
    returnModel.Operators = getOperatorsTask.Result

    Return returnModel
End Function
```

The problem I'm encountering is in my `getItemNameAsync` and `getOperatorsAsync`:

```
Async Function getItemNameAsync(itemTypeID As Integer) As Task(Of String)
    Dim itemName = (From row In db.tblCategories
                    Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemTypeID
                    Select row.Item_Type).SingleOrDefault()

    Return itemName
End Function
```

This function gives me a warning:

> This async method lacks 'Await' operators and so will run synchronously.  Consider using the 'Await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'Await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

I was under the impression that the `Await` in `getItemHistory` would take care of this issue for me.

What is the proper way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: It's more appropriate to start at the "leaves" (that is, the database access functions) and change those to use asynchronous APIs *first*. Then let `async`/`await` grow from there until your controller method is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either make `getItemNameAsync` not marked as `async` and just have it be synchronous (but this will require you to change `getItemHistory`) or if you are using Enity Framework you need to use it's extension method [`SingleOrDefaultAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220228(v=vs.113).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to make it return a task.

```
Async Function getItemNameAsync(itemTypeID As Integer) As Task(Of String)
    Dim itemName = Await (From row In db.tblCategories
                    Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemTypeID
                    Select row.Item_Type).SingleOrDefaultAsync()

    Return itemName
End Function
```

You could also make it not `Async` and just return the task directly.

```
Function getItemNameAsync(itemTypeID As Integer) As Task(Of String)
    Dim itemNameTask = (From row In db.tblCategories
                    Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemTypeID
                    Select row.Item_Type).SingleOrDefaultAsync()

    Return itemNameTask 
End Function
```