# Threading error, A second operation started

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm using VB.Net, Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5 and EF6.  I've implemented asynchronous functions as was suggested to me on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106363/mvc-net-view-model).  I've declared all my tasks `Async` as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913533/vb-net-async-using-await-properly).  I have no errors or warnings in my solution and everything works as intended the first time through the asynchronous action.  However if I try to use that same action later in the same session I'm greeted with an error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This error is thrown on a different task every time.

This is my controller action:

```
<SecureRoleByItemID>
<Route("ViewDetails/ViewHistory/{itemID:int}/{itemType:int}")>
Async Function ViewHistory(itemID As Integer, itemType As Integer) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ActionResult)
    Dim viewModel = New ItemHistoryViewModel

    Dim model = Await viewModel.getItemHistory(itemID, itemType)

    Return View(model)
End Function
```

This is my function that creates the view model:

```
Async Function getItemHistory(itemID As Integer, itemTypeID As Integer) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ItemHistoryPresentationModel)
    Dim returnModel = New ItemHistoryPresentationModel

    Dim getOperatorsTask As Task(Of List(Of String)) = getOperatorsAsync(itemID)
    Dim getItemNameTask As Task(Of String) = getItemNameAsync(itemTypeID)
    Dim getChangeDatesTask As Task(Of List(Of Date)) = getChangeDatesAsync(itemID)
    Dim getAssignedEmployeesTask As Task(Of List(Of String)) = getAssignedEmployeesAsync(itemID)
    Dim getChangeTypesTask As Task(Of List(Of String)) = getChangeTypesAsync(itemID)
    Dim getLocationIDsTask As Task(Of List(Of Long)) = getLocationIDsAsync(itemID)
    Dim getEditHistoryIDsTask As Task(Of List(Of Integer?)) = getEditHistoryIDsAsync(itemID)


    Await Task.WhenAll(getOperatorsTask, getItemNameTask, getChangeDatesTask, getAssignedEmployeesTask, getChangeTypesTask, _
                       getLocationIDsTask, getEditHistoryIDsTask)

    returnModel.UniqueItemID = itemID
    returnModel.ItemTypeID = itemTypeID
    returnModel.ItemTypeString = getItemNameTask.Result
    returnModel.DatesChanged = getChangeDatesTask.Result
    returnModel.Operators = getOperatorsTask.Result
    returnModel.AssignedEmployee = getAssignedEmployeesTask.Result
    returnModel.ChangeType = getChangeTypesTask.Result
    returnModel.LocationIDs = getLocationIDsTask.Result
    returnModel.EditHistoryIDs = getEditHistoryIDsTask.Result

    returnModel.LocationNames = getLocationNames(returnModel.LocationIDs)
    returnModel.Edits = getEditHistoryValues(itemID, returnModel.EditHistoryIDs)

    Return returnModel
End Function
```

And this is the simplest of the tasks that has thrown the error:

```
Async Function getItemNameAsync(itemTypeID As Integer) As Task(Of String)
    Dim itemName = Await (From row In db.tblCategories
                    Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemTypeID
                    Select row.Item_Type).SingleOrDefaultAsync()

    Return itemName
End Function
```

I have checked multiple times that each function is `Async` and is using `Await`.

I have not received this error the first time through the action.  It comes if the user views the history of one item, then navigates to the main menu and back to the history of another item.  When the user attempts to view the history of an item the second time through is when I encounter this error.

Am I missing something that closes or resets the threads at the end of the action, or can you see what would cause this from my implementation?

Comment: Where do you create `db`? Usually you do this in the controller's constructor. Then, you shouldn't need to worry about multiple concurrent context accesses. But there seems to be a query that has not returned yet.

Comment: @NicoSchertler currently db is created at the top of the class, before the function.  I will try moving it inside.

Comment: That should be fine (because it actually becomes part of the constructor). It is not `Shared` or anything, is it? Do parts of the query perform another query (e.g. in the property referenced by the `Where` clause)?

Comment: @NicoSchertler it's declared as `Private db As New Model1`.  I'm not sure how to tell if it's performing a second query, all of the information in these queries are coming from the same table.  I was under the impression that it's just one query, select a value where this value is located.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Moving the declaration into the functions as opposed to the top of the class seems to have resolved the issue.  I just performed the action that was consistently causing the error ten times in a row with no issue.

Comment: Although this solved the issue, I would strongly encourage you to find the reason for your problem. It might turn up again any time.